# How to open Whats app application from my application on click of button and code to put the value on search contact bar of whats app application

Tags: android

In Whats app Application having a search contact bar in the top of the application ,in my application there is one search button and text box with text "ayush",when i am clicking On search button of  my application  want to open whats app and want to showing the same value("ayush") on search bar of whats app application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is only share intent: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012
And I didn't find any web API to do it.
So, I think, you can't do what you want.